# How can I shorten this code by using a structure?

Tags: swift, structure

I just started to learn about Structures, I think it can be solved by using Structures but I am not sure.

Case: I have a VC with a lot of achievements the player can unlock. 
Every achievement has:
1. border image around the achievements image and text
2. achievement image (every achievement have a simple "lock" image to indicate that the achievement is locked)
3. achievement text
4. a boolean to determine the state of the achievement(false=locked, true =unlocked)
While playing the game, some achievements can be accomplished. That way, the boolean will be set to true. When the player return to the achievement VC, the achievement image must be set to the correct image for that achievement.

Problem: I now have my code as followed:

```
func SetImagesForPowerUps()
    {
        if UnlockedAchievement1 == true
        {
            Achievement1Text.textColor = UIColor.greenColor()
            Achievement1Image.image = UIImage(named: "Achievement1Unlocked")
        }
        if UnlockedAchievement2 == true
        {
            Achievement2Text.textColor = UIColor.greenColor()
            Achievement2Image.image = UIImage(named: "Achievement2Unlocked")
        }
    }
```

As you can see, I must repeat my code over and over, and it is a lot of work overtime. I am sure there is a faster way for this, except I do not have the knowledge to know to I can solve this in a quicker way.

Question: How can I shorten this code to make it work?

Comment: Have you ever heard about Arrays and For in loops?

Comment: I use arrays already in my code, I understand that concept! For in loops however not. I am not sure what to use. How would you answer my question by using for in loops and arrays?

Comment: If you are not too concerned about MVC then sub class your powerups and add variables to hold the data you need, then make an array of the subclass in your VC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

//how many achievements?

```
var achievements:[Bool] = []
var achievementText:[UILabel] = [] //I am not sure what achievementText Parent class is
var achievementImage:[UIImage] = [] //AchievementImage is subclass of UIImage? Not sure what achievementImage parent class is. 

for index in 0 ..< x 
    //Where x is the number of possible achievements, default all achievements to false at the very beginning of the app or wherever.
    achievements.append(false)
}

func SetImagesForPowerUps() {
    for index in 0 ..< achievements.count { 
        if(achievements[index]) {
            achievementText[index].textColor = UIColor.greenColor()
            achievementImage[index].image = UIImage(named: "AchievementUnlocked")
        }
    }
}
```

Then you when they unlock an achievement, you determine what level they are on. Then set `achievements[level+1] = true` `//(If you use levels starting at 1)`

Comment: You asked on July 24th, I answered on July 24th

Comment: Not you, but my response